# SelectLayerByLocation_management not filtering in ArcGIS Pro/ArcGIS Server arcgispro-py3 instance

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-pro, mosaic-dataset

For some reason, `SelectLayerByLocation_management` is not filtering with arcgispro-py3 instances from ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and ArcGIS Server 10.9. Filtering works fine using ArcGIS Server 10.9 python2.7 installation. The mosaic dataset has about 280K rasters and the AOI polygon should only return a subset of matching OIDs based on intersect with the Mosaic Dataset footprint layer. I tried setting `arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem` to the MD SR (4326) before calling `SelectLayerByLocation_management` but that didn't work. Am I missing something?

```
import arcpy

path_md = r'H:/Data/Raster.gdb/MD1'
path_aoi_geojson = r'H:/Data/aoi.json'
PATHS = r'in_memory\paths'

with open(path_aoi_geojson) as f:
    geojson = json.loads(f.read())
ft = geojson['features'][0]
path_aoi = arcpy.AsShape(ft['geometry'], False)

arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management(path_md, 'MD_Lyr')
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(r'MD_Lyr\Footprint', 'INTERSECT', path_aoi)

oid_list = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(r'MD_Lyr\Footprint' ,"OID@"))

print(str(len(oid_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug on a VM using ArcGIS Server 10.9/ArcGIS Pro 2.8 arcgispro-py3 `BUG-000143287`.